# Sortable post metabox

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I am trying to create sortable posts metabox.
I have custom post type "ba-product" in which i have created a metabox for manually select related posts and i also want to create manually post order. now i am stuck here how can i save the order with metabox so it just apply on foreach loop with metabox not to main posts.I really don't know if this is possible.

```
<div id="related-products">
      <ul id="rp-list">
       <?php
       $products = get_posts(array('post_type' => 'ba-product', 'numberposts' => '-1', 'orderby' => 'none'));
       foreach($products as $product) {
       ?>
          <li id="<?php echo $product->post_name.'-'.$product->ID; ?>" class="related-products">
            <h3 class="hndle">Move</h3>
            <div class="inside">
            <label class="selectit">
            <input id="<?php echo $product->ID; ?>" value="<?php echo $product->ID; ?>" name="brp[rp][]" type="checkbox" />
            <?php echo $product->post_title; ?>
            </label>
            </div>
          </li>
       <?php } // ends $products ?>
      </ul>
  </div>
```

JS

```
jQuery( document ).ready( function($)  {
    $('#rp-list').sortable({
        handle      : 'h3.hndle',
        tolerance   :'pointer',
        update : function () {
            var neworder = new Array();
            $('#rp-list li').each(function() {    
                var id  = $(this).attr("id");
                var obj = {};
                obj[id] = id;
                neworder.push(obj);
            });
            $.post("post.php",{'neworder': neworder},function(data){});
        }
    });
});
```